# Looking for one book for preparation for the exam of level A1 in European Portuguese

Tags: português-europeu, recursos

Olá! I'm in the first steps of learning European Portuguese and I am looking for a book that contains all necessary preparation (theory and practice) for the exam of level A1 / A2 in European Portuguese by Instituto-Camões.

Comment: I didn't know Instituto Camões did exames/certification of Portuguese as a foreign language. (Last time I checked was quite a few years ago, and from what I gathered the exame was seldomly taken and finding organized classes abroad outside the immigrant community wasn't easy.)

Comment: Although your question is surely about Portuguese Language, it's off topic here because there isn't one right answer, but several.

Comment: @Centaurus , does this condition also apply to a question on [tag:recursos]?

Comment: The question is completely off-topic.

Comment: @stafusa  It's how I see it.  When there isn't **one right answer**, how can the OP choose it?  How can we upvote it?   Questions asking for suggestions or trying to bring about discussion on a topic shouldn't be welcome, or else SE is going to turn into a forum.  PS: if you want further discussion on this, let's do it at Meta, or Falatório.

Comment: @Centaurus Yes, good suggestion. I've been reading up on that and will postpone the discussion until after the election.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn european portuguese you can start with "Português XXI". We used this book at the university (the 1st year).

https://www.amazon.it/Portugues-Xxi-Edicao-Caderno-Exercicios/dp/9897523898/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?keywords=portugu%C3%AAs+xxi&qid=1582168073&sr=8-1

I also suggest the book " Gramática átiva 1", in which you can find grammar rules and more exercises.

https://www.amazon.it/Gram%C3%A0tica-activa-1-en-portugais/dp/9727576389/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?keywords=gramatica+ativa+1&qid=1582169183&sprefix=gramatica+ativa&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any indication of books, but I will point you three sites:

https://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/portuguese.php

http://hackingportuguese.com/tips-and-tricks/practicing-listening-comprehension/

They also teach European Portuguese:

https://www.instituto-camoes.pt/en/activity-camoes/what-we-do/learn-portuguese

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest the book " Gramática átiva 1", in which you can find grammar rules and more exercises.

https://www.amazon.it/Gram%C3%A0tica-activa-1-en-portugais/dp/9727576389/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?keywords=gramatica+ativa+1&qid=1582169183&sprefix=gramatica+ativa&sr=8-1